# mysql to access to excel connection

Tags: mysql, excel, database, ms-access, connection

So this has been an issue for days already and I could not find any solution to it.
I have successfully connected a table of a remote mysql database (hosted on my own server) to a MS access (ver. 2013) file stored on the desktop of my laptop which runs win 7 ultimate.

All changes being done in each side will be reflected on the other side of the link. So far, no problem.

The issue is that I have an excel datasheet containing the same table but with updated records. I was able to get it imported by right clicking on the imported ODBC table and choosing Import Excel file and then choosing the append a copy of data to the existing table.

That worked only for the first time as it inserted all rows into the originally empty remote table. After that, every time I repeat the same thing, none of the updated records will be reflected into the linked remote-table.

Any lights on the matter is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: consider of using Talend Open Studio which allows you to define the migration process and export it as a scheduled job. by then, you can automate the task without repeating it

Comment: I'm downloading it now from https://www.talend.com/    Thank you man, i hope it will do the job for me.